# Multinode cluster only recognizes 1 live node (Slave node only)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have installed multi node Hadoop 
1 master and 1 slave 
Data node worrks fine, but when I check for yarn nodes 
I open http://master:8088/cluster/nodes i find only one node connected which is the slave node, and I cant see the master node.

Is this normal, or there should be tow nodes, master and slave?